# tex4ht discards added spaces

Tags: spacing, conversion, tex4ht

`tex4ht` discards the added spaces in this document when converting to `.odt` format (`pdflatex file && mk4ht oolatex file`).

Is there a way to write spacing commands that `tex4ht` will preserve?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blankline}{\par\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\shiftright}{\par\hspace*{1em}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
One
\blankline
Two
\shiftright Three 
Four
\blankline
Five
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no surprise, you must provide custom configurations for your own commands, for example using following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\blankline}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<text:p text:style-name="blankline"></text:p>}\par}
\renewcommand{\shiftright}{\par\HCode{<text:span text:style="shiftright">&nbsp;</text:span>}}
\OOstyles{%                                                                                                                                           
  <style:style style:name="blankline" style:family="paragraph" 
         style:parent-style-name="Text-body">
    <style:paragraph-properties             
       fo:margin-top="0.0cm"               
       fo:margin-bottom="0.0cm"           
    />                                   
  </style:style>                        
}
\OOstyles{%
  <style:style style:name="shiftright" style:family="text" 
 >
    <style:text-properties
    fo:padding="1cm"
    />                                   
  </style:style>                        
}

\EndPreamble
```

It inserts [OpenDocument Elements](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part1.html#__RefHeading__1415202_253892949) in place of your commands and configures some styles associated to them. Note that spacing at the beginning of line doesn't work, it obviously needs some other style than I've used. I may take a look at this issue tomorrow.

[image]

Comment: Does any spacing command need a custom configuration?

Comment: @AndrewCashner `\bigskip` and `\medskip` works in HTML, they don't seem to be configured in `odt` output